# "Занять" файл на время

Tags: c#

Разрабатываю приложение, которое участвует в цепочке перемещения файлов. То есть: как только в папке 1 появляется файл, мое приложение его считывает оттуда, записывает в папку 2 (сетевую), и из папки 2 его сразу забирает другое приложение. В данный момент копирование файлов реализовано следующим способом:

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile);
File.WriteAllBytes(targetFile, byteArray);
```

Мне необходимо добавить расчет хеша файла до копирования (в папке 1) и после копирования (в папке 2) чтобы определять, не повредился ли файл в процессе копирования. Проблема в том, что как только мое приложение записывает файл в папку 2, его сразу же оттуда забирает (перемещает) другое приложение, и я не успеваю прочитать файл для расчета его хеша. Изменить логику этого другого приложения нельзя.

Мне необходимо выполнить следующее: сразу после копирования каким-то образом "занять" файл в папке 2, чтобы успеть считать его оттуда и рассчитать его хеш, после чего "отпустить" его. Прошу подсказать, каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: *как только мое приложение записывает файл в папку 2, его сразу же оттуда забирает (перемещает) другое приложение* Это другое приложение перемещает ЛЮБОЙ появившийся в папке файл? Тогда только если явно открывать файл, записывать, читать (предварительно, возможно, сбросив кэширование), считать сумму, и лишь при прохождении проверки закрывать. Пока файл открыт, дальнее приложение фиг его переместит...

Comment: А если это приложение не сильно рассчитано на 'занятость' файла? Сломается? Загадит лог/консоль ошибками? Упадет? Аварийно завершиться? Более не будет обращаться к заблокированому файлу вообще?   Вот эти вопросы надо для себя сначала прояснить, перед тем как придумывать блокировки.

Comment: @NewView *А если это приложение не сильно рассчитано на 'занятость' файла?* Этого не может быть. Иначе оно начнёт регулярно ломаться, обращаясь к этому файлу в процессе его записи - `File.WriteAllBytes` процесс не мгновенный...

Comment: Быть может всякое :) это факт, но проверить надо. Наверняка это реализовано через файл-ватчер, и по окончанию заливки и свободности файла он инициализирует событие, где и происходит обработка. А вот в обработке, скорее всего настанет момент - кто первый откроет файл :) приложение автора, или приложение копировальщик. И тут вопрос спорный как оно себя поведет при невозможности открыть существующий файл.

Comment: И непонятно зачем рассчитывать кеш из записанного файла когда у вас есть содержимое этого файла? Кто вам мешает расчитать кеш или заранее, из исходного файла или из содержимого в процессе копирования? Само по себе архитектурное решение не верное.

Comment: @NewView Хеш исходного файла рассчитывается из массива байт, прочитанного из исходного файла. Затем этот массив байт записывается в другой файл. В процессе записи целевой файл может повредиться, для проверки этого нужно заново считать целевой файл и рассчитать его хеш.

Comment: Ну и рекомендация, не надо изобретать велосипед, есть же системная функция копирования `File.Copy`. Если файлы большие, то ваш метод копирования весьма не оптимален, и отъедает память в размер файла+.

Comment: А копировальщик файла на сервере вашего производства? Или сторонние решения? И как вам поможет рассчитанный кеш, если файл уже скопирован и обработан другой программой? Какие действия предпримет ваша программа? И на мой взгляд, ситуация с испорченными файлами при передаче по локальной сети минимальна. Там полно механизмов контроля, если использовать системную функцию копирования и проверять коды возврата и ошибки.

Comment: @NewView Копировальщик файлов, который забирает файлы из папки 2, это стороннее решение. Пока что действий программа не будет предпринимать, если обнаружит, что файл испортился, сейчас это нужно только для записи в журнал - успешно ли передался файл.

Comment: Посмотрите [FileInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) - откройте через него, запишите, и не закрывая прочтите, сравните и т.д. потом закройте если все удачно.Если нет - удалите файл и запишите в журнал :)

Comment: *Наверняка это реализовано через файл-ватчер, и по окончанию заливки и свободности файла он инициализирует событие, где и происходит обработка.* ... и значит, по окончании заливки надо сначала перечитать его, посчитать сумму, и только потом закрыть и освободить.

Comment: Кстати, а как себя ведёт то самое стороннее приложение, если у него нет прав на перемещение обнаруженного файла? а как именно оно его переносит? ну или по крайней мере - переносит в пределах одного тома или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чисто в теории кода:

```
FileStream s2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```

должно быть достаточно что бы залочить файл.

Еще гуглится вот такой вот ответ интересный: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522256/4423545

возможно, тебе будет полезен так же.

Comment: После того, как залочили файл этим методом, каким образом его разлочить? s2.Close() ?

Comment: Наверно закрыть FileStream :) и .Dispose() не забыть

Comment: @zigr0lf ньюВью тебе все правильно ответил)

Comment: @NewView поправка: закрыть FileStream  и не забыть Dispose - это одно и то же

Comment: я этим и предлогал закрыть поток (Dispose) :)